# Lindblad form for a Damped harmonic Oscillator

Tags: hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, density-operator, dissipation, open-quantum-systems

I'm considering a Lindblad-like master equation for a damped harmonic oscillator
$$
    \frac{d\rho(t)}{dt} = -i[H, \rho(t)]+\sum_{n,m=1}^2 h_{nm}[A_n \rho(t) A_m^\dagger
     - \frac12 \lbrace A_m^\dagger A_n,\rho(t)\rbrace ],
$$
where $H$ is the oscillator Hamiltonian. The Lindblad operators are  $A_1=a^\dagger$ and $A_2=a$, where $a$ ($a^\dagger$) is the annihilation (creation) operator. When we talk about an $N$ level system, and the operators $A_n$ are orthonormal with respect to the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, then the master equation is Lindbladian (completely positive and trace preserving) if the matrix with elements $h_{nm}$ is positive semidefinite. If we truncated the number basis here, then we could rescale the Lindblad operators to be orthonormal. But obviously the full Hilbert space is infinite and so is the norm of the operators. Is there any extension of the Lindblad formalism to deal with the infinite Hilbert space. Is there a similar restriction on $h_{nm}$?